# Cocoa Touch - animating the center property of an UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation

I have this UIView that contains two identical UIImageViews juxtaposed.
I am looking to make this view translate from right to left and, when the view reaches the end, instantly reset its center to default to give the illusion of continuity.

My problem is that when I set the default center in a non-animation block, the passage is animated and I see my view 'rewinding'.

This is the code I am using:

```
-(void)drunkenMove{

int newCenterX=40;

BOOL animation=YES;


CGPoint newCenter;
if(starView.center.x<=-0){ //so the view has reached the end, being 960*320
newCenter=CGPointMake(480, starView.center.y); //create a reset center
    animation=NO;
}else{
newCenter=CGPointMake(starView.center.x-newCenterX, starView.center.y); //else move on
    animation=YES;
}
    if (animation==YES) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        starView.center=newCenter;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }else{
        starView.center=newCenter; //here I want to set the center instantly
        [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        starView.center=CGPointMake(480+newCenterX, starView.center.y);;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

}

I am expecting to see my center reset then animated, but I also get an animation of the center being reset.
Any idea why?
I have encountered a similar problem with others UIView animations so I think I may have missed something.
By the way, this function is called by a cycling thread.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

My problem was somehow created by the method

```
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
```

From UIView class reference:
Discussion
Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. Instead, you should use the animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: method to specify your animations and the animation options.

I hope this can save some time to someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use almost the same method as you and for me it works. Perhaps `[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];` causes your problem but I'm not sure.

Comment: Mind to post your method if it does the same work as the one I formulated? Also, I tried to change that property. I got a behaviour slightly different, but still I have the view 'rewinding'.

Comment: overlay.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
  CGRect theFrame = overlay.frame;
  [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
  
  if(inVisible) {
   theFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(overlay.superview.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(theFrame);
  }
  else {
   theFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(overlay.superview.bounds);
  }
  
  overlay.frame = theFrame;
  [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: oh, i completely deleted the line you indicated and now it works like a charm. Gotta go read better the documentation about that property. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your "reset"

```
starView.center=newCenter;
```

in the else clause is getting wrapped up automatically for efficiency by CoreAnimation in the following animation that you create. Just get rid of that animation:

```
}else{
    starView.center=newCenter; //here I want to set the center instantly
    //[UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
    //[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    //[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    //[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    //starView.center=CGPointMake(480+newCenterX, starView.center.y);;
    //[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

and the subview will "jump" the way you want. The movement animation will start up again on the next cycle of this method.

Comment: You are right, my problem is that my cycling thread calls that method every 0.3 sec, so if I remove the animation I get a delay of 0.3 seconds between the reset and the next animation. Surely a workaround can be done, but I want to understand why this is happening!